# Newline (linebreak) after contenteditable div content

Tags: html, css

How can a newline (linebreak) be inserted after the first line of text in a *contenteditable* `div` so that when focusing the element, the caret is at the beginning of the the next line?

Additionally, at least Firefox and Chrome wrap the existing content and the added text in child divs *after* hitting Enter (Return), eliminating an inserted `<br>`.

```css
div{border:solid 1px black;}
.b {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="b" contenteditable>nothing</div>
<div class="b" contenteditable>br<br></div>
<div class="b" contenteditable>two brs<br><br></div>
<div class="b" contenteditable>linebreak
</div>

<div class="b" contenteditable>two
lines
</div>

<div class="b" contenteditable>nobreakspace after linebreak
&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="b" contenteditable><div>childdiv inherits, with br</div><br>
</div>

<div>
<div contenteditable>work</div>
<div class="b" contenteditable></div>
</div>
```

Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution when playing with the code snippet: use two [Line Breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), `<br><br>`.

Works in Firefox 94.0.2 and Chrome 96.0.4664.93 on Windows 10.